# Using SELECT with UNION

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE members
(
name        varchar(60),
ID          char(6)         PRIMARY KEY
); 


CREATE TABLE ratings
(
memberID    char(6)            REFERENCES members(ID),
rating      SMALLINT CHECK(rating >= 1 AND rating <= 8),
gameID      integer            REFERENCES games(ID),
    PRIMARY KEY (memberID, gameID)
);
```

Hi guys, I'm trying to list all the members who have rated a game or not with showing the Max rate, Min rate,average rate, and how many times they have rated.

I tried :

```
    (SELECT MAX(rating), MIN(rating), AVG(rating), COUNT(rating), name
FROM ratings, members
WHERE ratings.memberID = members.ID
GROUP BY name) 
    UNION
    (SELECT   MAX(rating), MIN(rating),  AVG(rating),COUNT(distinct rating), name
FROM ratings, members
WHERE 
members.ID NOT IN (SELECT  memberID
FROM ratings, members
WHERE ratings.memberID = members.ID)
GROUP BY name);
```

This first part gives me a correct values; it gives the correct names followed by Max, min, and count, and the average. But the second part gives a correct names but wrong values of Max, Min, Average. It gives a Max of 9 and Min of 2 for all members who didn't rate any game! Which is not true. How can i fix the second part , so it gives a value of zero instead of 9 and 2 ?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get the result set you are looking for by using either a `LEFT` or `RIGHT` join

```
SELECT 
    M.name,
    MAX(rating),
    MIN(rating),
    AVG(rating),
    COUNT(rating)
FROM
    [members] M
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [ratings] R
ON 
    M.ID = R.memberID
GROUP BY 
    M.name
```

This would then give a results like

```
name    max    | min   | average  |  count
name1    8     | 2     |    5     |   3
name2    NULL  | NULL  |  NULL    |   0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd rewrite that query using `INNER JOIN` syntax, as it is clearer why the joins bring back unexpected results. As you'd written it, the second query would join all results against all members that had no results, per:

```
SELECT   MAX(rating), MIN(rating),  AVG(rating),COUNT(distinct rating), name
FROM ratings, members
WHERE 
members.ID NOT IN (SELECT  memberID
FROM ratings, members
WHERE ratings.memberID = members.ID)
```

I suspect you were after something more like:

```
SELECT      MAX(rating), 
            MIN(rating), 
            AVG(rating), 
            COUNT(rating), 
            name

FROM        ratings

INNER JOIN  members
    ON      ratings.memberID = members.ID

GROUP BY    name

UNION

SELECT      MAX(rating), 
            MIN(rating),  
            AVG(rating),
            COUNT(distinct rating), 
            name

FROM        ratings

WHERE       ratings.memberID NOT IN (SELECT  memberID FROM members)

GROUP BY    name
```

Comment: Using an `INNER JOIN` would not show members who have not rated anything a `LEFT` or `RIGHT` join should be used.

Comment: what does inner join do ?